# How to set multiple styles to word paragraph using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to set multiple styles for same paragraph only one style will apply. I want apply multiple styles

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("D:\\LatestStyleTemplates.docx"));
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\createdocument.docx"));
            XWPFParagraph article = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFParagraph title = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFParagraph endnoteText = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFParagraph heading1 = document.createParagraph();
            endnoteText.setStyle("Strong");
            endnoteText.setStyle("EndnoteText");
```

Comment: Does Microsoft Word even allow you to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single paragraph level style per paragraph. You can have additional character styles defined in runs (max of one per run) if you need to override specific aspects of the paragraph style.